# Create VIP plot using R from the SIMCA VIP values

Tags: ggplot2

I am using SIMCA software to perform multivariate analysis and want a VIP scores plot in R as shown below. [image: I want this plot from the VIP scores I retrieved from SIMCA]

which package is used for this type of plot (image retrieved from Google-images)??

Comment: Just a minutes VIP for SIMCO is Variable Influence Projection and the OP i assume wants to reproduce that in R because it is free. SIMCO is comercial.VIP has been used to quantufy transcriptomics via ML, but thats completely different VIP

Comment: Anyway the ML framework for VIP Variable Importance Plots in R is here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vip/readme/README.html